# climbing the mountain

Tags: meaning-in-context, past-simple, past-continuous, continuous

As I understand *"I climbed that mountain"* means that *I reached the top of it*.

So If the climbing was interrupted and therefore not completed, we **must not** say *"As we **climbed** the mountain, our guide fell and slipped"* and it **must be** the continuous form *"As we **were climbing** the mountain, our guide fell and slipped"*, right? Common sense and logic tell me, "Yes, that's right".
But one native speaker told me that the simple form is OK, as well. How is that possible?

> As we **climbed** the mountain, our guide fell and slipped.
> As we **were climbing** the mountain, our guide fell and slipped.

(the climbing was interrupted and therefore not completed)

Comment: No, the simple past is fine. They just emphasize different things.

Comment: @Lambie how is the past simple fine if we didn't climb the mountain (to the top of it)?

Comment: Because when you say, "as we climbed the mountain, x happened" is not about reaching the top of the mountain. climb a mountain in some contexts can imply reaching the top but not all contexts mean that.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your first statement is not correct.

In general, the choice of aspects in English (continuous vs. simple, and perfect vs past) do not reliably convey differences in objective reality. They convey a choice in how the speaker is choosing to present the events.

Of course there is a correlation between simple past and completed events, but it is not inevitable.

*As* is not inconsistent with the simple past: it simply provides a different way of putting us in the middle of the activity - so the continuous aspect, while possible, is not required. (To my ear, *As we climbed* sounds more formal or old-fashioned than *as we were climbing*. But both are normal.)

Comment: Thank you. I've always been told that the simple past implies completion, and that I can't reply to "What did you do yesterday?" with "I wrote my book" if I didn't finish it yesterday. How does 'to climb' differ?

Comment: It doesn't. With a telic predicate (such as _climb a mountain_ or _write a book_) in a main clause, it probably does indicate that the action is complete. But in an _as_ clause, it doesn't have that implication.